# SQL SMO exception causes finally block to be skipped?

Tags: sql, try-catch, smo, finally

I created a VS2010 Windows service project.  In it I invoke the method Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.ExecuteWithResults(expression).  In my scenario the expression contains invalid SQL, so the call fails with an exception as expected.

What's not expected is that the method is invoked within a try/finally block, but the finally block is NEVER executed:

```
try { database.ExecuteWithResults(invalid-sql) } 
finally { // code here is NOT executed }
```

However, if I change it to a try/catch/finally block, both the catch and finally code is invoked.

```
try { database.ExecuteWithResults(invalid-sql) } 
catch(Exception) { // code here is executed fine }
finally { // as is this code }
```

Am I missing something here?  Shouldn't a finally block always get executed?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, go to Debug | Exceptions..., you can try checking different level exceptions to be "thrown".
Before I only saw this happening to some 3rd party win32 dlls, and they could be caught by checking more exception types in that dialog.